# Grassmannians of planes isotropic with respect to general tensors

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

In symplectic geometry, the Grassmannian of isotropic planes for a symplectic vector space is a well known and well studied object; for example, one can realize it as a homogeneous space with a known stabilizer subgroup of the symplectic group, and one can also realize a Schubert cell decomposition.

However, one can relax the symplectic condition in two ways: by relaxing its degeneracy condition, and by allowing it to take vector values (i.e., allowing for general tensors). A good example generalizing both of these situations can be found from the study of distributions: for any given distribution $D$ on a tangent bundle $TM$ of some smooth manifold $M$, there is a natural (O'Neill?) torsion tensor $T \in \Gamma(\wedge^2D^* \otimes TM/D)%$ defined by:

\begin{equation}
T(X,Y) = [X,Y]  \text{ mod }D
\end{equation}

Clearly, $T$ is a skew symmetric bilinear map. However, its degeneracy could vary depending on the distribution. On one hand, $T = 0$ identically gives that $D$ is integrable. On the other, it being nondegenerate gives that $D$ is maximally non-integrable and is a contact structure. One can still make sense of planes isotropic with respect to $T$, as the planes on which $T$ vanish identically.

> Is there anything known about the isotropic Grassmannian of planes
>   with respect to the above tensor (e.g., is it homogeneous with respect
>   to a nice known Lie group? Can one describe its Schubert cell
>   decomposition?)? With respect to more general settings/tensors as above?

I imagine in the case of the above particular tensor, one treats each component of the vector as a (possibly degenerate) symplectic form but I have not seen anything about it in the literature, so I'm hesitant to declare everything should be *exactly* the same as for the standard Grassmannian of isotropic planes with respect to an ordinary symplectic form.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are asking about is very classical in the theory of exterior differential systems.  The subspaces of $D$ that you are calling `isotropic' are what Élie Cartan called the *integral elements* of the differential ideal $\mathcal{I}$ generated by the sections of $D^\perp\subset T^*M$ (the annihilator subbundle of $D$).  The geometry and topology of these spaces of integral elements can be quite subtle, and a significant part of the basic theory of exterior differential systems is devoted to developing ways to describe these subspaces of the Grassmann bundles, particularly deriving necessary and sufficient conditions that a given integral element $E\subset D_x\subset T_xM$ should be a tangent space of an *integral manifold*, i.e., a submanifold $N\subset M$ all of whose tangent spaces are sub-planes of the plane field $D$.  This leads to the Cartan-Kähler theory and beyond.

For references, you can look in our book *Exterior Differential Systems* (Bryant, et. al) or in *Cartan for Beginners* (Ivey and Landsberg).

Comment: Can one say anything about the fundamental group in the above case? eg, if we are considering complex planes, is it simply connected? I would imagine so since any reasonable Schubert cell decomposition should only involve even dimensional cells ...

Comment: @TobiasShin: I believe that the answer to the question over $\mathbb{C}$ is 'no'.  The first example I can think of is the generic case when $M$ has dimension $10$ and $D$ has dimension $5$. In that case, generically, there will be no $3$-dimensional integral elements, and, at each point, the space of $2$-dimensional integral elements will have dimension $1$. In fact, it will be a smooth curve of degree $5$ lying in a projective space of dimension $4$ and it will have genus $1$, so it will be an elliptic curve, which is topologically a (real) $2$-torus.  Hence, it will not be simply connected.

Comment: how do you reconcile the above with the following theorem (in Gunning and Rossi's Analytic Functions of Several Complex Variables): if $X$ is an irreducible complex variety whose universal cover $\tilde{X}$ is an irreducible analytic space, then for any closed analytic subspace $Z$ inside $X$, we have $\pi_1(X-Z)$ surjects onto $\pi_1(Z)$.

It seems like in the above situation, your $X$ is the Grassmannian of 2-planes in 5-space, and your $Z$ is of codimension 5. But removing a submanifold of real codimension at least 3 should not change the fundamental group.

Comment: Ack sorry I think there might be a typo... they might mean surjective onto $\pi_1(X)$

Comment: @TobiasShin:  I'm not familiar with this result, but you must be misunderstanding it.  If what you claim were true, then an elliptic curve could not appear embedded in a $6$-dimensional projective space (which is clearly simply connected, compact, and irreducible), and that is obviously false, since an elliptic curve can appear embedded in a projective space of any dimension at least 2.  Until you explain why this result doesn't apply in this simpler and obvious case of a non-simply connected curve in a simply connected compact variety of high dimension, I don't really have anything to do.

Comment: I explained it above, there was a typo. My mistake.

Comment: @TobiasShin:  Sorry, your correction didn't show up in my feed until after I posted my reply to your question.